# Finding Pose variation of a face using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

In an image there is a face, which is tilted a bit and has a slight pose variation. Using opencv i detected the co-ordinates of eyes, nose, and mouth. Using these 4 points is it possible to re-align this face into an ideal frontal face ? 
I tried out perspective transformation, which did work for a few images, but gave horrible results for most of the pics. Is there any other way of re-aligning the image into an ideal frontal face without any tilt or pose variation?

Comment: Can you please post images that you had nice results and the ones with horrible results, so we can see what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can refer the [Procrustes Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_superimposition) to get more help. 
The idea would be to find a rigid transformation matrix from the ideal human face to the actual human face using a set of known points. Then use the inverse of this transformation matrix to each point on the actual human face to get back the ideal one.

Here you have a set of known points (two eyes, tip of nose and mouth). You can assume an ideal position for them. From the image detection using OpenCV, you get 4 corresponding points. 
Also you could refer to [Kabsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) if you can assume only rotations are possible, which I think might make sense in your case.
There is a nice question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77462/finding-transformation-matrix-between-two-2d-coordinate-frames-pixel-plane-to-w) explaining the above topics.
I hope the above references help you.

Comment: Thanx for the help Unni. I dont have much idea about these two algorithms,but will refer both and try to work it out...!!

Comment: Best of luck, cameo. I have never worked in this particular problem, but might work on something similar in near future. I hope I also could use this later.